# Elasticsearch make an OR query instead of AND query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to create prioritized search results using the n-gram filter. The priority should be as follows:

1. Full text match
2. Match at the beginning of the word
3. Match at the middle of the word
4. Match at the end of the word

My idea was to split a property into a multiple fields and give a boost to each of them.

My analysis:

```
                'ngram_index_analyzer': {
                    'type': 'custom',
                    'tokenizer': 'keyword',
                    'filter': [
                        'lowercase',
                        'multiplex',
                        'ngram_filter',
                    ]
                },
                'edge_ngram_index_analyzer': {
                    'type': 'custom',
                    'tokenizer': 'keyword',
                    'filter': [
                        'lowercase',
                        'edge_ngram_filter',
                    ],
                },
                'back_edge_ngram_index_analyzer': {
                    'type': 'custom',
                    'tokenizer': 'keyword',
                    'filter': [
                        'lowercase',
                        'back_edge_ngram_filter',
                    ],
                },
```

and my filters:

```
 'ngram_filter': {
                'type': 'ngram',
                'min_gram': 2,
                'max_gram': 20,
            },
            'edge_ngram_filter': {
                'type': 'edge_ngram',
                'min_gram': 2,
                'max_gram': 20,
            },
            'back_edge_ngram_filter': {
                'type': 'edge_ngram',
                'min_gram': 2,
                'max_gram': 20,
                'side': 'back',
            },
```

Then I split a property into multiple fields, assigning corresponding filter to each of them:

```
        'substring': {
            'type': 'text',
            'analyzer': 'ngram_index_analyzer',
            'search_analyzer': 'search_analyzer',
            'boost': 0.5,
        },
        'prefix': {
            'type': 'text',
            'analyzer': 'edge_ngram_index_analyzer',
            'search_analyzer': 'search_analyzer',
            'boost': 0.7
        },
        'ending': {
            'type': 'text',
            'analyzer': 'back_edge_ngram_index_analyzer',
            'search_analyzer': 'search_analyzer',
            'boost': 0.2
        }
```

I expect the result of the query to be as follows:

1. Market changes
2. Some market purposes
3. Food market

but instead, it just sums up the boost value and all results are kinda random. For example, 'Some marketing stuff about market' can appear higher than 'Market discussion' as it has 2 matches (for middle and ending).

Is there a way to rebuild the query so each match would be unique and result in OR instead of AND?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to totally understand your use case.
But,regarding your mapping, does the Multi-match with the best_field strategy could answer to your needs?
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html.
It's the same a a dis_max with a tie_breaker of 0.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-dis-max-query.html

You can query on the 2 fields and depending on the boost, only the score for the best field is used.

Official documentation:

> **best_fields** The best_fields type is most useful when you are searching for multiple words best found in the same field. For
> instance “brown fox” in a single field is more meaningful than “brown”
> in one field and “fox” in the other.
>
> The best_fields type generates a match query for each field and wraps
> them in a dis_max query, to find the single best matching field. For
> instance, this query:
>
> ```
> GET /_search
> {
>   "query": {
>     "multi_match" : {
>       "query":      "brown fox",
>       "type":       "best_fields",
>       "fields":     [ "subject", "message" ]
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Normally the best_fields type uses the score of the single best
> matching field, but if tie_breaker is specified, then it calculates
> the score as follows:
>
> the score from the best matching field plus tie_breaker * _score for
> all other matching fields